# Batch Stop Program A on Launch Program B, Start Program A on End Program B

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I synchronize my documents using Google's sync program. However, I don't want the sync program meddling with my project files when I have certain programs open. My attempted solution is below.

This is a really clunky way to attempt to turn off program A when program B launches, then turn program A back on when program B stops running. The batch script below does this effectively, but it takes a sizable chunk of processor power (between 1 and 4% on my mobile i5 8th gen). Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'm willing to consider other tools (ie, AutoIT).

EDIT, per suggestion, I added a simple 15-second timeout at the end, which makes this program acceptably processor intensive (ie, not). Running this via task scheduler as hidden makes this a working solution.

```
@echo off
rem mutually exclusive program enforcer

rem initialize variables
set gDriveOn=init
set reaperOn=init

rem begin infinite loop for monitoring on states
:loopStart

    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq reaper.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "reaper.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    set reaperOn="TRUE" 
    goto gDrivecheck
    )

rem else if reaper not found
set reaperOn="FALSE"

:gDriveCheck    
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq googledrivesync.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "googledrivesync.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    set gDriveOn="TRUE" 
    goto doStuff
    )

rem else if Google Drive not found
set gDriveOn="FALSE"

:doStuff
rem turn off gdrive when reaper is on
if %reaperOn% == "TRUE" (
    if %gDriveOn% == "TRUE" (
        taskkill /f /t /im googledrivesync.exe
        )
    )

if %reaperOn% == "FALSE" (
    if %gDriveOn% == "FALSE" (
        start  C:\"Program Files"\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe
        )
    )

rem delay 15 seconds for efficiency
timeout 15
goto :loopStart
)
rem end of infinite loop
)
```

Comment: I cannot find `doMoreStuff:` line in your source code. Try opening a command prompt and running it from there: this way if there is a syntax error you will see what it is. If this does not help please edit your post and include logs of its operation (i.e. copy all text from command prompt window after running the script)

Comment: There were a couple issues with the code - both of which I fixed in the last edit - thanks. However, this takes an unacceptable amount of processing power. I'm looking for a more efficient solution.

Comment: You have at least one syntax error: `domorestuff` needs to start with `:`. You *really* need to make sure the code you posted works exactly as you described - run it and test it. If your code is no longer misbehaving, please edit the question and remove the clause about dying.

Comment: I did fix the code - but I apparently didn't post it despite my comment stating I had. Polling is a slightly better solution, and the pid truck is clever in AutoIT. I'm surprised if there isn't a low resource way to monitor if a program is running built in to Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because posted source code doesn't run I won't yet attempt to answer stability part of the question. See my former comment on suggestion how to debug it yourself.

As for performance:

### Batch file delays

if I didn't miss anything, this code is constantly requesting if a pair of processes exist. That is, it starts the next check right after previous one completes, again and again with no pause inbetween.

This basically instructs your computer to devote all available processing power to checking process existence. This program should theoretically be using 100% CPU, but since for some reason listing tasks under Windows is slow and inefficient, and you probably have more that one CPU core, and batch processing is slow itself it only is able to use a fraction of CPU.

You most likely do not need to check processes that frequently. This is usually done once in 1 to 10 seconds. If this is acceptable, insert a delay somewhere in the code like this:

```
TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK
```

where 5 is seconds to wait. See `timeout /?` or [this](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) for more information.

### AutoIT

In AutoIt you will need `ProcessExists()` to check process existence and `Sleep()` to insert a delay. Killing a process is accomplished with `ProcessClose()` and `Run()` starts one. The documentation is available [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/) under `Function Reference`

Checking processes on windows is still slow and inefficient. AutoIT documentation suggests that `the process is polled approximately every 250 milliseconds` which probably implies that if you try to request it any faster you will get results it saved from the last time, so it makes sense to insert a `Sleep(250)` or more.

However, this mostly applies to querying process by name which requests a list of all running processes and searches yours in it. This does not need to be done if you know a process already exists - you can simply use its Process ID number (PID) to check if it stopped - which should be faster. So instead of just `ProcessExists("notepad.exe")` you could do something like this:

```
local $pid = 0
while true
  if ($pid <> 0) then $pid = ProcessExists($pid) ;Process already existed, use PID
  if ($pid = 0) then $pid = ProcessExists("notepad.exe") ;Process did not exist
  if ($pid <> 0) then 
       ;do something if process exists...
  endif
  sleep(300)
  .........
wend
```

This works because `ProcessExists()` returns PID if process exists or 0 if not.
First `if` line runs if `$pid` was already known from last time we checked. 
If it wasn't or if we never checked before or if it was but no longer exists then second line runs and does the check based on process name. This should be repeated for the second process. Please note this is intentionally not `if-then-else` because 1st check may set `$pid` to `0`.

### EXE replacement

If the solutions above do not work -- for example because the `reaper.exe` just crashes horribly if it happens to attempt accessing something `googledrivesync.exe` is holding -- then something else should probably be done.

One option is to rename `reaper.exe` to `real_reaper.exe` and compile an autoit script into new `reaper.exe` that kills `googledrivesync` and starts `real_reaper.exe`. This script needs to pass all parameters so something like

```
RunWait ('"real_reaper.exe" ' & $CmdLineRaw)
```

should do the trick. This waits for `real_reaper.exe` to finish running and then you can do `Run("googledrivesync.exe")`

This may not work properly if the program that starts `reaper.exe` uses some tricks but it should work in most cases.